# disable http2 in seanmonstar/warp

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-warp

I built a small web app using the crate `warp`. As it runs behind a reverse proxy, is it possible to build the warp crate without support for http2, so that compile time and binary size is reduced?

Comment: https://github.com/seanmonstar/warp/pull/836

Answer (score 0):

`warp` does not reexport the `http2` feature it enables in `hyper`, but maybe you can try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65468297/8182118

> It's not ideal but if you add your sub-dependency as a dependency the feature is going to work.

Basically add our own dependency to `hyper`, and only copy over the dependencies you want to keep.